# How to sort data in sql query (according to value present in the json format of a data base field)

Tags: php, mysql, json

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [20] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [qopid] => 20

                    [data] => {"room":0,"category":0}

                )

            [21] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [qopid] => 21

                    [data] => {"room":0,"category":0}

                )

            [22] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [qopid] => 22

                    [data] => {"room":0,"category":0}

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [23] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [qopid] => 23

                    [data] => {"room":"3","category":0}

                )

            [24] => stdClass Object
                (

                    [data] => {"room":"3","category":0}

                )

            [25] => stdClass Object
                (

                    [data] => {"room":"3","category":0}

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [26] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [qopid] => 26

                    [data] => {"room":"4","category":0}

                )

            [27] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [qopid] => 27

                    [data] => {"room":"4","category":0}

                )

            [28] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [qopid] => 28

                    [data] => {"room":"4","category":0}

                )

        )

)
```

Here I want data to be come in view as whose room is 0 , should always come last ([data] => {"room":0,"category":0})

Means I want room zero data should always come last.

below is my sql query

```
 $sql = 'SELECT q.*   FROM ' . \SystemTables::DB_TBL_QUOTATION_PRODUCT . ' q  LEFT JOIN ' . \SystemTables::DB_TBL_ITEM . ' ii ON q.iid = ii.iid   WHERE q.qoid = "' . $qoid . '" ';

                if ($rooms == 0)
                {
                    $like = "'" . '%{"room":' . $rooms . ',%' . "'";
                }
                else
                {
                    $like = "'" . '%{"room":"' . $rooms . '",%' . "'";
                }
                if ($cat_id != null && $cat_id > 0)
                {
                    $like1 = "'" . '%[{"id":"' . $cat_id . '"}]%' . "'";
                    $sql .= ' AND c_catid LIKE ' . $like1 . '';
                }


                $sql .= ' AND q.data LIKE ' . $like . '';
```

Above is my sql query , how to do it ? as the sort by is not an exact column.
I need to do sort by room which is present inside data .

Comment: You want just the array sorted or you want to create the sql query with those that has `rooms : 0` be last on the statement?

Comment: I want array to be sorted , but room 0 should always come last in the array list .

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is a nested `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {   // Loop thru each array
    foreach ($value as $object) {      // Loop thru each object
        $data = $object->data;         // Set data value to $data
        $decode = json_decode($data);  // Decode $data string
        if ($decode->room == 0) {      // Check if room is 0
            $move = $array[$key];      // Set array value to $move
            unset($array[$key]);       // Unset array first
            $array[$key] = $move;      // Then add array to last
        }
    }
}

print_r($array); // print array
```